# Thunderbird on Windows to Evolution on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, thunderbird, evolution

I am replacing a hosed Windows installation with Ubuntu.  I am trying to migrate emails from Thunderbird on XP to Evolution on Ubuntu.  I've slaved in the Windows drive and I tried to import from the Thunderbird mailbox into Evolution but it seems Evolution doesn't recognize the file.  I installed Evolution on the Windows installation and was able to import from Thunderbird to Evolution on Windows, but can't recreate it on Ubuntu.

Any advice out there?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a fake GMail address, configuring the IMAP server, and copying my emails that way.  It seemed to work well.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing Thunderbird on Ubuntu.

You may try installing an IMAP server such as Dovecot and saving your folders to it. Evolution will be able to read from the IMAP server.

Also consider using something like fetchmail to read your POP mailboxes and drop them into your IMAP inbox.

Comment: I did install Thunderbird on Ubuntu, but it ran like garbage and I couldn't get it to do anything before it would crash.  I suppose I can try that route again.

I think GMail has IMAP support, correct?  Would it be possible to import into GMail from Thunderbird, and then pull down into Evolution?